# Php script /java script to help put two dual dynamically generated drop down menus

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Though am not new to php scripting, and I do have a problem with combining it with JavaScript for this purpose of mine. 
I have a form, contains a category dropmenu, selected category modified the options available for the subcategory dropdown menu... I have been able to do this with php and javascript 
My problem is in that same form I have the state and city dropdown menus dynamically generated, anytime the state is selected, and the option selected in the subcategory is wiped off. 
Any help with how to combine this 2 different classes of dropdown menu together on the same page?

Here are the major codes related to my problem.

```
function reload(form)
{ 
  var val=form.cat.options[form.cat.options.selectedIndex].value;
  var val1=form.location.options[form.location.options.selectedIndex].value;
  self.location='reg_practice_details.php?cat=' + val  + ''location=' + val1 ;
}
```

```
<?php 
  @$location=htmlentities($_GET['location']);
  @$cat=$_GET['cat'];

// Getting the data from Mysql table for first list box
  $quer2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT class_id,class FROM categories order by class"); 
// End of query for first list box

// for 2nd dropdown check if category is selected else display the subcategory
  if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0){ 
    $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategories where class_id=$cat order by subcategory"); 
  }
  else{
    $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategories order by subcategory"); 
  } 
// end of query for 1st group of drop down list box 

//Dropdown menu for state and city
$sql2=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT state_id,state FROM state order by state"); 

// for second drop down list we will check if category is selected else we will display all the subcategory 
if(isset($location) and strlen($location) > 0){

$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM city where state_id=$location order by city"); 

}else{$sql=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM city order by city"); } 

// end of query for second group drop down list box
?>

<form action="details.php" method="post" name="practiceDetails"> 
//Dropdown code for the category/subcategory group of dropdown menu

<?php 
// Add your form processing page address to action in above line.
//        Starting of first dropdownlist
  echo "<select name='cat' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\">
  <option value=''>Select one</option>";

  while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($quer2)) { 
    if($noticia2['class_id']==@$cat){
        echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[class_id]'>$noticia2[class]</option>"."<BR>";
    }
    else {
        echo"<option value='$noticia2[class_id]'>$noticia2[class]</option>";
    }
} 
echo "</select>";
?>

<?php
  echo "<select name='subcat'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
  while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($quer)) { 
echo  "<option value='$noticia[subcategory]'>$noticia[subcategory]</option>";
} 

echo "</select>";?>
///Dropdown code for the state/city group of dropdown menu

<?php 
echo "<select name='location' onchange=\"reload(this.form)\">
      <option value=''>Select one</option>";

while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql2)) { 
   if($noticia2['state_id']==@$location){
      echo "<option selected value='$noticia2[state_id]'>$noticia2[state]</option>"."<BR>";
   }
   else{
      echo  "<option value='$noticia2[state_id]'>$noticia2[state]</option>";}
   } 
echo "</select>";
?>

<?php
    echo "<select name='city'><option value=''>Select one</option>";
    while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) { 
       echo  "<option value='$noticia[city]'>$noticia[city]</option>";
    } 
  echo "</select>";?>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, try to show us what you have tried already

Comment: I just did by editing my question to include codes.. . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

it looks like your javascript is selecting both menu's. 
--> that's not it...

There are a few typos, like

```
self.location='reg_practice_details.php?cat=' + val  + '&location=' + val1 ;
```

a missing `}` in a while loop, and a few others.

But aside those, what you are trying to do is as follows: if a user makes a selection on the `cat` or `state` dropdown-menu, respectively the `subcat` and `city` dropdown-menus should change and offer only the applicable values.

Like I said, you are refreshing the complete form (`reload(this.form)`) to change one dropdown menu. You're setting the `selected` values by using `$_GET` variables. These are retrieved from the URL, so changing the form does not reload the full page, and will thus not pickup any (new) `$_GET` vars. (funny, this error is on all execersis floating around the web. Either wise your teacher/prof created a goof, or doesn't understand client/server-side programming)

There are two possible options.

1. let PHP echo the database results into Javscript (as an Array). The browser will pick this up, and Javascript can access to those results. You then use javascript's onChange() method to detect any changes to `cat` and `state` dropdown menus, and if detected, let javascript re-create/re-fill the correct dropdown menu with sub-options (thus `city` or `subcat`)
   Although this is not the nicest, it is the easiest.

   ```
   // Getting the data from Mysql table for first list box
     $class_query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT class_id,class FROM categories order by class"); 

   // get all subcategories, we do the 'where class_id=$cat on the client-side 
     $subcat_query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategories"); 

   //Dropdown menu for state and city
     $state_query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT state_id,state FROM state order by state"); 

   // get all the cities, we'll check for the state ( state_id=$location) client-side
   // note that getting DISTINCT cities, means that if cities appear in more states,
   // they're not fetched... 
     $city_query=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT city FROM city order by city");
   ?>
   ```

   .

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   var class_array = Array();
   var subcat_array = Array();

   <?php
   // prepare all dropdown menus.
   // the output is written as javascript (JS) arrays
   // as the browser loads the page, it reads the arrays as JS, and JS can use it
   // position this somewhere in your <body>, after the queries, before the form

     while($noticia2 = mysql_fetch_array($class_query)) {
       echo "class_array = [" . $noticia2[class_id] . "] = " . $noticia2[class];
     }

     $n=0
     while($noticia = mysql_fetch_array($subcat_query)) { 
       echo "subcat_array = [".$n."] = {
                            subcategory: \"" . $noticia[subcategory] . "\"
                            class_id: \"" . $noticia[class_id] . "\"}";
       $n++;
     }
   ?>
   </script>
   ```

   you can then use javascript to slice the array where the class_id in subcat_array equals the class_id from the selected element in the class submenu. (in this example it's an object, but a multidimensional array can as well
2. another possibility is to use AJAX. AJAX, in short, retrieves the results in a separate call. So in javascript, you use the `onChange()` like the above option, but instead of refilling the the dropdown-menu with a slice of the array, you make an AJAX-call to a php file that does the original sql-query

   ```
   if(isset($cat) and strlen($cat) > 0)
   { 
     $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategories where class_id=$cat order by subcategory"); 
   }
   else
   {
       $quer=mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT subcategory FROM subcategories order by subcategory"); 
   }
   ```

   The ajax call will receive the results (obviously you need to `echo` your query-results in that php file) and you can use that to (re)populate the dropdown-menu. 
   Since AJAX implementations vary per browser/OS, using a library like jQuery can significantly make things easier. (the jQuery documentation is also great).

Whichever option you chose, this should give you some starting points to get going. As this is an exercise from some kind of homework, I'm not giving you the full code ;) (also, don't have a PHP testing environment atm.)

*some things to think about*

- There's an excessive use of `@$var`. There's really no need to
  suppress errors, so don't :).
- If this code comes from a tutorial,
  find another. The code is clearly old, Google returns questions on it
  from 2007. In 2007 this code was so-so, now it's a clear no-no.
- If
  you get any specific errors/questions along the way, search SO/google
  it, or create a new specific question.

Hope you can get a tad further now!

Comment: Please read the about page (http://stackoverflow.com/about) while I look at your code. You learn something about SO and earn a badge! (also, i made some edits to your post...)

Comment: Please I will like to know if there is a way of doing this without reloading the page because I need the catergory/subcategories dropdown menu as well as the state/city dropdown menu on the same page.. Am open to new and better ways please.

Comment: The syntax error didn't provide the solution... Please I need help

Comment: Thank you,@puredevotion.. I await your aid as I stay glue to my screen